# How to redirect Tomcat logs back to catalina.out instead of syslog?

Tags: opensuse, syslog, tomcat

In the release notes for `openSUSE 13.1`, developers proudly stated that `Tomcat` logs are no longer being written into `catalina.out`, but rather written to `syslog`. I saw similar behaviour with new distributions, but now it's my problem also. I really don't know why it is considered as improvement. And that's why,

1. My Tomcat installation is used as a playground for several
   developers, and I hardly want to share my syslog with them.
2. The webapp under `Tomcat` is pretty verbose with logs (since it is under development) and I don't want to put all these garbage in to the syslog.

There are a plenty of tutorials on how to redirect Tomcat log into syslog, but I need to perform reverse operation. Any ideas?

**UPD:** Here is my `tomcat.conf`, nothing suspicious there:

> JAVA_HOME="/etc/alternatives/jre"
>
> CATALINA_HOME="/usr/share/tomcat" CATALINA_BASE="/usr/share/tomcat"
>   CATALINA_TMPDIR="/var/cache/tomcat/temp"
>
> SECURITY_MANAGER="false"
>
> SHUTDOWN_WAIT="30"
>
> SHUTDOWN_VERBOSE="false"
>
> CLEAR_WORK="false"
>
> CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms2G -Xmx8G -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=4G"

Comment: what is your tomcat config ? (not oblige to put every virtual host)

Comment: does the catalina.sh still present ?

Comment: Yes, it's present. I have found some acceptable solution. I will publish it in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tomcat` being installed from openSUSE repo runs as a service under `systemd`. According to [this page](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2012-March/004702.html), it is not possible to redirect output of systemd-controlled services directly to the file. Thus, I have the only option left: filter messages from `syslog` when they got there.

I have created file `/etc/rsyslog.d/tomcat.conf` and put these lines there:

> :programname,contains,"tomcat" /var/log/tomcat/tomcat.log
>
> :programname,contains,"tomcat" ~

This works fine for me.

**UPD 2018:** Nowdays every developer would rather have own Tomcat instance unpacked into a folder, not installed system wide. Or even one embedded into the program, that could be done in Spring Boot for example.

Comment: Any idea how to do this for syslog-ng?